# Sys:Info perl module to get memory and space information

Tags: linux, perl, unix

Does any one have idea about how to use sysinfo to get info like swap memory , memory used , available memory , load average , total physical memory , total cache memory.
I am new to perl.

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.spec.org/mpi/docs/sample-sysinfo-program.pl

Answer (score 2):

[sysinfo](http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/Linux-SysInfo-0.13/lib/Linux/SysInfo.pm)

```
use Linux::SysInfo qw/sysinfo/;

my $si = sysinfo;
print "$_: $si->{$_}\n" for keys %$si;
```

Comment: Can't locate Linux/SysInfo.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.4 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12 .) at demo1.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at demo1.pl line 2.

Comment: #!usr/bin/perl
use Linux::SysInfo qw/sysinfo/;

my $si = sysinfo;
print "$_: $si->{$_}\n" for keys %$si;

Comment: @AlexAnderson Well, you obviously have to install a module prior to using it. Run `cpanm Linux::SysInfo`, or use `cpan` if you don't have `cpanm` installed. But I wouldn't make any guarantees if this modules works as expected on OSX, which you seem to be using.

Comment: Thanks @amon . I need to figure this out.